# Where is the flaw in my algorithm to find all pairs in an array whose sum divides k?

Tags: c#, algorithm, linq

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here.

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
class Solution
{
    static void Main(String[] args) 
    {
        string[] lineParts = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
        int k = Convert.ToInt32(lineParts[1]);
        int[] arr = Array.ConvertAll(Console.ReadLine().Split(' '), Int32.Parse);
        var indices = Enumerable.Range(0, arr.Length - 1);
        int pairsDivideK = (from i in indices
                            from j in indices
                            where i < j && ((arr[i] + arr[j]) % k == 0)
                            select 1).ToList().Count / 2;
        Console.WriteLine(pairsDivideK);
    }
}
```

Input:

```
6 3
1 3 2 6 1 2
```

Expected Output:

```
5
```

My output:

```
1
```

Comment: `select 1).ToList().Count / 2` why are you doing this ?

Comment: @user3185569 I'm dividing by 2 to account for repeats

Comment: And why should i be less than j ? and why you're not using the first value in linesParts which is 6 ? Can you at least explain why are you doing each step.

Comment: You're already accounting for repeats with i < j, so you don't need to account for them a second time by dividing Count by 2

Comment: @user3185569 this is a typical HackerRank exercise. And they allow there solutions to be given also in languages other than c#. And you may need to know the number of elements to allocate the array in some other language. But for simplicity, the test-cases are always equal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you don't have to divide by 2. Because of the `where i < j` condition there are no repeats.

Second: you have to use `Enumerable.Range(0, arr.Length)` (no `-1`) as the second parameter is not the upper limit but the count of elements.

So your code should be:

```
...
var indices = Enumerable.Range(0, arr.Length);
int pairsDivideK = (from i in indices
                    from j in indices
                    where i < j && ((arr[i] + arr[j]) % k == 0)
                    select 1).ToList().Count;
Console.WriteLine(pairsDivideK);
```

Comment: I think he's dividing by 2 to get the number of pairs and not to skip duplicate passes.

Comment: You get `1` for each matching condition i.e. you get the number of pairs (=5:  1,2 / 1,2 / 3,6 / 2,1 / 1,2). Your approach would also get 5 as result but you also use the wrong `Enumerable.Range` parameters.

Comment: Or to use **index** pairs: 0,2 / 0,5 / 1,3 / 2,4 / 4,5